# Configuration file differences between building with Visual Studio and the MSBuild command-line tool

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, assembly-binding-redirect

I have a solution that contains a project with AutoGenerateBindingRedirects set to "true". When I build it via Visual Studio 2013, the .config file in the output directory contains an generated assembly binding redirect for EntityFramework, and the project runs. However, on the build server, which calls MSBuild, this property is not followed, which causes the project to fail to start. Does anyone have any idea on why there might be differences in the build results between the two methods?

For reference, the build server is executing a command like

```
MSBuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release,DefineConstants="SOMETHING" /t:Rebuild /tv:4.0
```

I get the same results when invoking this on my development machine, too, so it seems to be a peculiarity with MSBuild and/or Visual Studio. I've tried variations like

```
MSBuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release,DefineConstants="SOMETHING",AutoGenerateBindingRedirects=true /t:Rebuild /tv:4.0
```

to no avail.